Define table schema in jhipster jdl
Is there any way to create a jdl file that contains a collection of entities to be created by jhipster that will automatically generate the schema for the domain objects and schemaName in the generated liquibase .xml files?
For example for generated Spring domain classes:
@Table(schema=“mySchema”,table=“myTable”)…

And the same for liquibase .xml
<createTable schemaName=“mySchema” tableName=“myTable”>

Right now I can generate the files, but they only contain the table names, and refactoring them is time consuming for something that seems like it should be possible.
